# Prove that if $ab \equiv 0 \pmod p$, where p is a prime number, then $a \equiv 0 \pmod p$ or $b \equiv 0 \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $ab \equiv 0 \pmod p$, where p is a prime number, then $a \equiv 0 \pmod p$ or $b \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

All I have right now is that the prime divisibility property may help with the then part of this problem.

Comment: What is the "prime divisibility property"? If it's what I think it is, then this is literally just a one-line application of the definition of congruence.

Comment: The prime divisibility property says that if p|(a1*a2*... ar), then p divides on of the a's. But now that I look at it, I don't think it helps here

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't help? What is a way to say $p | a$ as a congruence?

Comment: hmmm... couldn't you write a= b+km from the definition of congruence?

Comment: No. That's the statement that $a \equiv b \pmod m$ (or modulo $k$). You should review the definition of $\mod p$.

Comment: I was thinking that but I thought it had to be at least a degree 2 to apply.

Comment: What do you mean by "it had to be at least a degree 2 to apply"? There's nothing here that has a degree.

Comment: I just assumed it had to be. I do understand now that you use this to solve the problem

Comment: @Matt What "degree"?

Comment: I thought it had to be at least degree 2

Comment: see [Unique_factorization_domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain)

Answer (score 0):

The ideal $(p) \subset \mathbb Z$ is prime, thus if $ab \in (p)$, then $a \in (p)$ or $b \in (p)$.

In other words:

$ab \equiv 0 \pmod p \implies ab=pk \implies p|a$ or $p|b \implies a \equiv 0 \pmod p$ or $b \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Comment: Just for clarification: what property is used here? I think I know but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: A prime number which divides a product must divide at least one factor.

Comment: This comes from the unique factorization in $\mathbb Z$ into prime factors.

Comment: That is what I thought it was. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in the integers, for a prime $\;p\;\;,\;\;\;p|a\iff a=kp\;,\;\;a,k\in\Bbb Z\;$ , and then $\;a=0\pmod p\iff p|a\iff a=kp\;$ , so by what you wrote in your second comment below your question:

$$ab=0\pmod p\iff p|ab\iff p|a\;\;\text{or}\;\;p|b\iff $$

$$a=kp\;\;\text{or}\;\;b=mp\;,\;\;k,m\in\Bbb Z\iff a=0\pmod 0\;\;\text{or}\;\;b=0\pmod p$$